# Issue with break in Javascript

Tags: javascript

If I put `break;` in else part, the alert does not pop ups..!

```
var i=1;
if(i==1)
{
     alert("hum");
}
else
{
    i=0;
    break;
}
```

If I remove the `break;` from else part, then, everything works fine! Is it my browser/server issue? If not I wonder Why this happens!

Comment: It is Illegal `break` statement, why you are using there?

Comment: Yes, what was the intent ? Did you confuse it with something else, like `debugger;` or `return;` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alert doesn't pop up because you have a syntax error ([visible in the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)) preventing the execution of the whole code.

You can't put a `break` anywhere, it has to be put into something breakable, for example a `for` or `switch` statement.

[break documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

> Terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers program control to the statement following the terminated statement.

When something doesn't work, please open the console first (F12 in most browsers).

Answer (score 5):

The alert does not pop up as you've introduced a javascript error, which stops *all* javascript executing

> SyntaxError: unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch
>   break;

Answer (score 3):

From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

> Terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers
>   program control to the statement following the terminated statement.

You do not have a loop or a switch. Can't break.

Answer (score 1):

Well above many people have already answered to your problem that use switch and use it specifically in loops or iterations

But if if really want to use break with simple if else then use label concept

below is code :

```
var i=1;
labelname:
if(i==1)
{
 alert("hum");
}
else
{
i=0;
break labelname;
}
```

here is the live example http://jsfiddle.net/h7Chd/1/